# Property [Photo] does not exist on this collection instance Laravel

Tags: laravel, session

i keep getting an error saying "Property [Photo] does not exist on this collection instance" .
I want to show the name of doctor in the view bienvenu.blade.php with using Session .

This is my **doctorcontroller.php** :

```
public function welcomedoctor (Request $request) {
    $rdv=rendezvous::get(); 
    $medecin_id=$request->session()->get('doc_id');
      return view ('/bienvenu',['med'=>$medecin_id] ,['pat'=>$rdv] );
}
```

This is the **bienvenu.blade.php**  :

```
  ...
      <img src="{{asset ('assets/img/uploads/'.$med->Photo)}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
      <h1 class="card-title"> Bienvenue Dr. {{$med->Nom}} {{$med->Prénom }} </h1> 
      <h3 class="card-text"> <i class='bx bx-plus-medical bx-rotate-270' style='color:#11709d'> </i>   
      {{$med->Spécialité}}</h3>   
  ...
```

This is web.php :

```
Route::get('/bienvenu','doctor@welcomedoctor');
```

Doctor Model :

```
class doc extends Model
{
    protected  $table = 'doctor' ;
    protected $fillable = ['ID' , 'Photo' , 'demande'];



    public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\blog');
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch the data of the doctor's ID from the database first. In your example you're sending the ID of the doctor in the variable `$med` to your view and not the doctor's data itself.

Here an example since I can only guess your model names based on your question history:

```
$doctorId = $request->session()->get('doc_id');
$doctor = doc::where('ID', $doctorId)->first();

return view('bienvenu', ['med' => $doctor, 'pat' => $rdv]);
```

Comment: Same problem :( i'm going to add the model in my post , please can you check it ?

Comment: Please capitalise the 'id' column ('ID') according to your model. It that's not working, dump the contents of `$doctor` and we'll see where the problem is.